# AngularFire2/Ionic3 - Facebook Authentication - Native Cordova - Reading object / Not updating html

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire, angularfire2

I hope this is the correct forum to ask this in, my alternative is Stack Overflow. But I've done everything as precisely posted in the article https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/Auth-with-Ionic3-Angular4.md and I believe it's working correctly on the phone, but I do not see my name. However, on the web app version, I do see my name. Was updating the `<h1>Hello {{ displayName }}</h1>` simply left out of the if `(this.platform.is('cordova')) {` part of the function?

***signin.ts***

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-signin',
    templateUrl: 'signin.html',
})
export class SigninPage {

    displayName;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
                private toastCtrl: ToastController,
                private platform: Platform,
                private fb: Facebook,
                private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
        afAuth.authState.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {
            if (!user) {
                this.displayName = null;
                return;
            }
            this.displayName = user.displayName;      
        });
    }

    signInWithFacebook() {
        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
            return this.fb.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then(res => {
                const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);

                return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
            })
        }
        else {
            return this.afAuth.auth
                .signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
                .then(res => console.log(res));
        }
    }

    signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    }

}
```

***signin.html***

```
<ion-header>

    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

    <h1>Hello {{ displayName }}</h1>
    <button ion-button outline (click)="signInWithFacebook()">Login</button>  
    <button ion-button outline (click)="signOut()">Logout</button>
</ion-content>
```

I see how I can subscribe to the `afAuth.authState`, but for Cordova, the `Facebook` package is used, so I'm not sure how to access the fields of the user or what the return object is. Thanks for any help provided.

If it helps, when ran on the android device, I see a Facebook box pop up for a brief period, maybe for 10 milliseconds, then disappear. This is why I think it's working (the authentication) but I just want to know how to access the user fields so I can print my name or grab a user id to associate with junk throughout the app that might go into a database.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
signInWithFacebook() {
        if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
            return this.fb.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then(res => {
                const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);

                return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(facebookCredential); // here is the change
            })
        }
        else {
            return this.afAuth.auth
                .signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
                .then(res => console.log(res));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, switching to that line you've provided results in a new error: `Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`. Trying to research into it to figure out why.